# ServerName not working Zend framework2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, localhost

I have installed xampp and Zend framework 2 on my system. when I run the code send frame work working good.
D: /xampp/htdocs/CommunicationApp/public its working good showing

Congratulations! You have successfully installed the ZF2 Skeleton Application. You are currently running Zend Framework version 2.3.4. This skeleton can serve as a simple starting point for you to begin building your application on ZF2.
but when I run Server name in the browser is showing xampp localhost page. please help me
server Name i have create:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName comm-app.local
 DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/CommunicationApp/public"
 SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
 <Directory D:/xampp/htdocs/CommunicationApp/public>
  DirectoryIndex index.php
 AllowOverride All
 Order allow,deny
 Allow from all
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have find out my answer.just rearrange my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
# fits all solution.
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
#RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

after rearrange .htaccess file ans restart my apache.Now working good.